# Pros and Cons of Facebook's React vs. Web Components (Polymer)

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, reactjs, web-component

What are the main benefits of Facebook's [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/) over the upcoming [Web Components](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/explainer/) spec and vice versa (or perhaps a more apples-to-apples comparison would be to Google's [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/) library)?

According to [this JSConf EU talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7cQ3mrcKaY) and the React homepage, the main benefits of React are:

- Decoupling and increased cohesion using a component model
- Abstraction, Composition and Expressivity
- Virtual DOM & Synthetic events (which basically means they completely re-implemented the DOM and its event system)

  - Enables modern HTML5 event stuff on IE 8
  - Server-side rendering
  - Testability
  - Bindings to SVG, VML, and `<canvas>`

Almost everything mentioned is being integrated into browsers natively through Web Components except this virtual DOM concept (obviously). I can see how the virtual DOM and synthetic events can be beneficial today to support old browsers, but isn't throwing away a huge chunk of native browser code kind of like shooting yourself in the foot in the long term? As far as modern browsers are concerned, isn't that a lot of unnecessary overhead/reinventing of the wheel?

Here are some things I *think* React is missing that Web Components will care of. Correct me if I'm wrong.

- Native browser support (read "guaranteed to be faster")
- Write JavaScript in vanilla JavaScript, write CSS in CSS, write HTML in HTML.
- Style encapsulation using Shadow DOM

  - React instead has [this](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html), which requires writing CSS in JavaScript. Not pretty.
- Two-way binding

Comment: This is a great question for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Done! http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/225400/pros-and-cons-of-facebooks-react-vs-web-components-polymer

Comment: Also, if someone with enough reputation on programmers.stackexchange.com could add some new tags for me (reactjs, web-component), that'd be great.

Comment: I posted my answer [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/225400/pros-and-cons-of-facebooks-react-vs-web-components-polymer/237762#237762)

Comment: why is "write CSS in CSS" a good thing...